# Fatal Error when executing GetFormattedValue() in phpExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a PHP code that inputs a dataset from MySQL to a column in an Excel template I created. The purpose of the Excel template is to take the dataset and use the `=FORECAST.ETS()` function of Excel.

I want to get the value of the `=FORECAST.ETS()` from Excel, so I used the `GetFormattedValue()` method of PHPExcel.

Here is my code:

```html
$phpExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($title);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($title);
//insert into database forecasted values
$ctr = 0;

while ($ctr != 13){
    //set the designate sheets to go to
    $sheet1 = $phpExcel ->setActiveSheetIndex($ctr);
    $date = $date = date('Y-m-d'); //today's date
    $subsegment = $segments[$ctr];
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $forecastrns = $sheet1->getCell('G2')->GetFormattedValue()."  ";
    echo $forecastarr = $sheet1->getCell('H2')->GetFormattedValue()."  ";
    echo $forecastrev = $sheet1->getCell('I2')->GetFormattedValue()."  ";
    echo "<br/></pre>";

    $ctr++;
}
```

When I open the resulting Excel, I can see that the `=FORECAST.ETS()` cell successfully calculated using the given parameters. However, when I try to retrieve the value of the `=FORECAST.ETS()`, I get this fatal error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'RCK!G2 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,' in C:\Users\Jade Ericson\Documents\GitHub\Forecast-Module-2\Prototype\PHPSCRIPTS\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php:291
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\Users\Jade Ericson\Documents\GitHub\Forecast-Module-2\Prototype\PHPSCRIPTS\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php(189): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue()
>
> #1 C:\Users\Jade Ericson\Documents\GitHub\Forecast-Module-2\Prototype\PHPSCRIPTS\JASON\ForecastWithTimespan.php(156): PHPExcel_Cell->getFormattedValue()
>
> #2 {main}
>
> thrown in C:\Users\Jade Ericson\Documents\GitHub\Forecast-Module-2\Prototype\PHPSCRIPTS\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 291

I have also tried the `GetOldCalculatedValue()` method, but it only returns `0`. All I want is to get the value of the `=FORECAST.ETS()`. I hope somebody can help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: The `FORECAST.ETS()` function is not supported by PHPExcel. It is one of the newer functions of MS Excel, and has never been implemented in PHPExcel

Comment: Is there no way for PHPExcel to directly access the value of the cell instead of the formula? I have lightly dabbled with VBA Macros and had slight hope but found out that PHPExcel does not support Macros. :(

Comment: `getValue()` returns the actual value in the cell..... and that value is the formula expression.... If MS Excel has previously calculate the formula itself, then it may be accessible to PHPExcel  via the `getOldCalculatedValue()` method; but this is not guaranteed to be the correct result. Otherwise you can't get a calculated value without calculating it

Comment: As I said earlier, **getOldCalculatedValue()** outputs **0**. There is a way to output the result. That is to open the generated .xlsx file and save it. when I run the **getOldCalculatedValue()** again, it outputs the correct calculated value. However, what I want to do is get the calculated value without actually opening the .xlsx file.

Comment: Simply not possible..... if the result of the calculation is not available via `getOldCalculatedValue()`, then the only possible way to get the result of that calculation is to actually calculate it..... when you `That is to open the generated .xlsx file and save it.`, then MS Excel is doing that calculation for you, and storing the result where a call to getOldCalculatedValue() can retrieve it. And unless the FORECAST.ETS function is implemented in PHPExcel, then PHPEcel cannot do that calculation, so prhaps look at implementing FORECAST.ETS in PHPExcel